# Extrair a capa de um MP3, e outras informações com PHP

Tags: php, html, arquivo

Tenho um arquivo MP3 em meu site, e gostaria de mostrar a capa desse MP3 no meu site, tem alguma forma de pegar essa capa com PHP, ou outra forma ?

Tipo esse site: https://mixstep.co/i0t9oz20ycb8

A capa e essa infos, estão dentro do MP3 e não foram colocados manualmente

**EXEMPLO:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa é uma bibioteca ou função que leia os tags ID3 de um arquivo MP3. Parece que tem alguma coisa na própria biblioteca padrão do PHP:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.id3-get-tag.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.id3.php

Comment: Pelo oque eu vi, só da pra pegar nome, e infos em texto.. mas nada da imagem.